# How to modify the images of input rtsp stream in Nvidia deepstream pipeline, before feeding to the model for inference?

Tags: object-detection, yolo, nvidia-deepstream, deepstream

I have set up a simple Deepstream application for yolo object detection, i am able to detect the object. Now I need to send a cropped and resized  version of input image for model inference, So where/how does I do that ?